# Is it possible to have different cleartype and color settings in a multimonitor setup in Windows 8?

Tags: windows, display, multiple-monitors, colors, cleartype

I just bought a Samsung 24C300HS and I have it connected to a Surface Pro. The color settings are horrible.

I used windows' "Calibrate color" to adjust the color and clearType settings and with that I can get a very reasonable image that I'm happy with, the problem is that it also changes the settings on the Surface Pro screen, making that one miserable.

Is there any way to get around this? For example having different color profiles for each monitor, or if not possible, is it possible to save the settings so that I can change them quickly without having to go through the Calibrate Color tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to run the "Calibrate color" tool (right click desktop->personalize->Display->Calibrate Color) with the external monitor connected in "expanded mode" so that both screens are visible.

If you run the calibration tool like this, you can just drag the calibration tool window to the monitor you want to calibrate(e.g. the external monitor) and it will only affect that monitor. ClearType adjustment will give you the option of choosing which monitor you want to calibrate when you have the external monitor in extended mode.