# ClearType settings per-screen

Tags: multiple-monitors, windows-8.1, cleartype

I am a bit confused about the per-screen ClearType settings. Some people say ClearType can *not* be turned **off** for a single screen in a dual-monitor setup, but a PowerToy is able to change the ClearType **settings** to be different for each screen.

My problem:

My primary monitor uses a BGR-subpixel layout, my projector uses RGB.
I want to keep ClearType turned on because default AntiAlias / no AntiAlias looks horrible and some programs don't even support that. I just want ClearType to render in the correct subpixel order on each screen.

Can I set it up that way? I am using Windows 8.1.

(How would that even work technically, Windows would need to redraw the window when moving it to another screen?)

Comment: Refer to this thread https://superuser.com/questions/732162/is-it-possible-to-have-different-cleartype-and-color-settings-in-a-multimonitor

Answer (score 0):

You could refer to this link here, as this problem has been solved already.

[Is it possible to have different cleartype and color settings in a multimonitor setup in Windows 8?](https://superuser.com/questions/732162/is-it-possible-to-have-different-cleartype-and-color-settings-in-a-multimonitor)

Comment: My appologies @Ramhound I am fairly new to SU.

Comment: @Ramhound Yes, however, I haven't used it since I created it.